# How to write a Java class file corresponding to a new entity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, entities

I actually have this entity class:

```
public class Item {
    private int m_Id, m_Number, m_Price;

    public int getId() {
        return m_Id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        m_Id = id;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return m_Number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        m_Number = number;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return m_Price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        m_Price = price;
    }
}
```

Where should I put `Item.java`?

I'm using Android Studio, and I want to have a proper project package structure. I read something about Endpoints, but I don't know what is it. Can you help me, please?

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand.

Comment: create a separate package for entity and put them in that

Comment: you can use android studio same as eclipse . So firstly learn about studio.

Comment: Based on your question I'd actually recommend not to worry about it at this early stage. Its very easy in Android Studio to refactor and later structure files to packages. Having that said, see my answer about using a package structure based on feature instead of class type. Or check a link for more lengthy answer: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Android developer consultant I often see a lot of different android projects with different package structure. While I see you are encouraged to put entities in a package called `entities` I just want to say I why I think its a bad idea. That is, instead of having packages named after type/layer

- entities
- activities
- fragments
- services ..etc

You structure package based on feature instead of type/layer, like so (taking a game for example):

- login
- highscore
- achievements
- core

This way, if you refactor the login feature of your application you should ideally only see changes in the `login` package instead of changes scattered all over you different packages (ex: *entities/Memeber.java, services/LoginService.java, activity/LoginActivity.java, fragments/SignupFragment.java* ...)

Another point is that the package names tends to be redundant as its very common to name the java files after their type (services/LoginService.java, activities/MainActiviy.java)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate package for all models in your source and put item.java there. i name it as model, you can name it anything you like.

Comment: Inside Java or com.android.tests? I mean: Java/Entities or Java/com.android.tests/Entities?

Comment: test folder is for creatiing test classes. choose your first option

Answer (score 0):

As [Project Structure Link](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

**Android Application Modules**

> An Android Application Module is the
>   container for your application's source code, resource files, and
>   application level settings, such as the module-level build file,
>   resource files, and Android Manifest file. The application module
>   contents are eventually built into the .apk file that gets installed
>   on a device.

**Test Modules**

> These modules contain code to test your application projects and are
>   built into test applications that run on a device. By default, Android
>   Studio creates the androidTest module for inserting JUnit tests.

So. `your.application.package.name.Test` is only for testing purpose. You can reference this sample structure. All your models should put into one package.
[image]

Hope this help :)

Comment: Nice, thanks you so much!

Comment: @Julián thanks. If you see this post useful, please upvote or mark it as accepted answer so other users can reference if they meet problem same as your case.